# Sorting dates (DD/MM/YYYY) with insertion sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, array, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm having troubles with a coding problem. Yes, I need to write a C++ program which sorts dates. I've tried several methods. Using 2D arrays and now parallel arrays.

The problem I have with my parallel array to keeping tract of those which haven't been sorted yet. That is the `YYYY` has been sorted. I need to keep track of the `MM`. Then `DD`.

Please make some suggestions as to how I should approach this. Or did I approach this question entirely in the wrong way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/*
Write a program in C++ to ask the user to enter dates in dd/mm/yyyy format.
The number of dates that the user can enter should also be specified by the user.
Sort the dates in ascending order using an appropriate sorting algorithm.
Also write a small description as to why you have chosen this particular sorting technique.

Example output screen:

Enter no of dates to enter: 5

Enter the first date: 12/05/1945
Enter the second date: 01/01/2001
Enter the third date: 05/12/1999
Enter the fourth date: 11/03/1972
Enter the fifth date: 15/12/1999

After sorting the dates are:

12/05/1945
11/03/1972
05/12/1999
15/12/1999
01/01/2001

*/



string ConvertToWord(unsigned int input) {
    string output = "";
    int ones_place = input % 10;
    int tens_place = (input - ones_place) % 100;

    if (input >= 10 && input < 20) {
        switch (ones_place) {
        case 0:
            output += "Tenth";
            break;
        case 1:
            output += "Eleventh";
            break;
        case 2:
            output += "Twelfth";
            break;
        case 3:
            output += "Thirteenth";
            break;
        case 4:
            output += "Fourteenth";
            break;
        case 5:
            output += "Fiftheenth";
            break;
        case 6:
            output += "Sixteenth";
            break;
        case 7:
            output += "Seventeeth";
            break;
        case 8:
            output += "Eighteeth";
            break;
        case 9:
            output += "Nineteeth";
            break;
        }
    }

    else if ((input >= 20 && input < 99) || (input > 0 && input < 20)) {
        switch (tens_place) {
            case 20:
                output += "Twenty";
                break;
            case 30:
                output += "Thirty";
                break;
            case 40:
                output += "Forty";
                break;
            case 50:
                output += "Fifty";
                break;
            case 60:
                output += "Sixty";
                break;
            case 70:
                output += "Seventy";
                break;
            case 80:
                output += "Eighty";
                break;
            case 90:
                output += "Ninety";
                break;
        }
        if (tens_place > 0 && ones_place > 0) {
            output += "-";
        }
        switch (ones_place) {
        case 1:
            output += "First";
            break;
        case 2:
            output += "Second";
            break;
        case 3:
            output += "Third";
            break;
        case 4:
            output += "Fourth";
            break;
        case 5:
            output += "Fifth";
            break;
        case 6:
            output += "Sixth";
            break;
        case 7:
            output += "Seventh";
            break;
        case 8:
            output += "Eighth";
            break;
        case 9:
            output += "Nineth";
            break;
        case 10:
            output += "Twentth";
            break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}

int* ToArray(string word) {

    word += "/";
    int* result = new int[3];
    string current_word = "";
    int num_words = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.at(i);
        if (c != '/') {
            current_word += c;
        }
        else {
            result[num_words] = stoi(current_word);
            current_word = "";
            num_words++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void ToArrays(int* days, int* months, int* years, int index, string input) {
    input += "/";
    string current_input = "";
    int num_input = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.at(i);
        if (c != '/') {
            current_input += c;
        }
        else {
            if (num_input == 0) {
                days[index-1] = stoi(current_input);
            }
            else if (num_input == 1) {
                months[index-1] = stoi(current_input);
            }
            else if (num_input == 2) {
                years[index-1] = stoi(current_input);
            }
            current_input = "";
            num_input++;
        }
    }

}

int** AddDatesInto2DArray(int** result, int _num_dates, string word, int index) {

    int* sorted_date = ToArray(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        result[index-1][i] = sorted_date[i];
    }

    return result;
}


void InsertionSort(int* array, int length) {
    int j, temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[j] < array[j - 1]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            array[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }

}

void InsertionSort(int* sorting, int* a, int* b, int length) {
    bool all_sorted = true;

    int* unsorted_index = new int[length];
    int* unsorted_sorting = new int[length];
    int* unsorted_a = new int[length];
    int* unsorted_b = new int[length];

    int j, temp, temp_a, temp_b;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        j = i;

        if (sorting[i] == sorting[j-1]) {

        }

        while (j > 0 && sorting[j] < sorting[j - 1]) {
            temp_a = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = temp_a;

            temp_b = b[j];
            b[j] = b[j - 1];
            b[j - 1] = temp_b;

            temp = sorting[j];
            sorting[j] = sorting[j - 1];
            sorting[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    cout << "Enter the number of dates to enter [Three Digit] : ";
    int num_dates = 0;
    cin >> num_dates;

    int* int_days = new int[num_dates];
    int* int_months = new int[num_dates];
    int* int_years = new int[num_dates];


    for (int i = 1; i < num_dates+1; i++) {
        string num_word = ConvertToWord(i);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the " << num_word << " date : ";
        string date_input = "";
        cin >> date_input;
        ToArrays(int_days, int_months, int_years, i, date_input);
    }

    InsertionSort(int_years, int_days, int_months, num_dates);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_dates; i++) {
        cout << int_days[i] << "/" << int_months[i] << "/" << int_years[i] << endl;
    }




    int i_temp = 0;
    cin >> i_temp;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the code: Nineth isn't the right spelling (ninth is), and Twentth should be tenth. And you're missing an `n` in the last three teens.

Comment: I would convert the date to an integer (e.g. 29/11/2000 -> 20001129) and then sort based on this. Then you avoid having to sort three times.

Comment: Your main problem: you need to sort dates, but you haven't modeled dates at all. Your code only contains a bunch of unrelated ints. Do as Winther suggests, or create a small `struct date` and use that. Also, remove all those plain arrays and use vectors. Your code leaks like there's no tomorrow.

Comment: All the 'convert to word' code is irrelevant to the problem that you're supposed to be solving — according to the specification in the code (which makes no mention of requiring dates spelled out).  So, a large portion of the code should be omitted.  Fortunately, the value in `ones_place` will never be 10; the word `"Twentth"` won't be generated.  It isn't clear that you handle zero; it may not matter for dates.  Your naming code doesn't handle negatives or numbers larger than 99 fully.  Have you heard of 'arrays'?  Are you sure you can't use some in your number-to-name code?

Comment: Is this code fully working and you'd like a review for possible improvements and good practices? Or, is there a bug and your main question is finding it? If the second (the bug), that's off-topic here: we review and improve code that works. Please clarify, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Major critiques:

1. There is no need for your `ConvertToWord` function. The problem statement does not say to do that. Your `ConvertToWord` is [gold-plating](http://blog.codinghorror.com/gold-plating/). (Aside: Your implementation has flaws.) Replace that 100 line long function with a simple `std::cout << "Enter date number " << idate << ": ";`

   **Edit**: On second thought, the problem statement does imply that something along the lines of `ConvertToWord` is needed. However, a good programmer will push back on stupid requirements. This is a stupid requirement.
2. There is no need for your two `InsertionSort` functions. Those two functions represent another big chunk of code, and they use insertion sort. Your first choice for a sort function should almost always be `std::sort`. Unless you have very weird data, `std::sort` will be much faster than a hand-rolled sorting function. Even if you do have very weird data to be sorted, your first thought should be `std::sort` with a custom comparison function.
3. There is no need for your `ToArray`, `ToArrays`, and `AddDatesInto2DArray`, either. You chose a poor representation. Sorting dates represented in the form `DD/MM/YYYY` is hard. On the other hand, sorting dates represented as a string of the form `YYYYMMDD` or an integer whose decimal representation is `YYYYMMDD` is trivial. Just use `std::sort` and you will get the correct sort order. Internally, you should have represented your data in some sort of `YYYYMMDD` format. Assuming properly formatted user input, converting from a string of the form `DD/MM/YYYY` to a string of the form `YYYYMMDD` is a one liner. Converting back to a string of the form `DD/MM/YYYY` is another one liner. This of course assumes perfectly formatted user input; a professional program would care very much about malformed user input. But the problem statement doesn't ask you to check for that. Those checks would be another form of gold plating here.
4. This is C++. In general, one should prefer one of the standard containers over C-style arrays. (This is not the case when doing numerical or scientific programming. But that's not what you are doing here.) In this case, a `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<int>` would be just right.

Lesser critiques:

1. Regarding `using namespace std;` -- Don't use that. In a professional code review, that is a sign of a rank beginner who has read the wrong books.
2. The standard idiom for an indexed loop in C++ is `for (i = 0; i < limit; ++i)` (in C the increment is written as `i++` instead of `++i`.) Anytime I see a indexed loop that is not in that form in a code review, I have to wonder why the author did that.

Instead of hundreds of lines of code,

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    int main ()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the number of dates to enter : ";
        unsigned int num_dates;
        std::cin >> num_dates;

        std::vector<std::string> dates;
        for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < num_dates; ++ii)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter date number " << ii+1 << ": ";
            std::string date;
            std::cin >> date;
            dates.push_back(date.substr(6) + date.substr(3,2) + date.substr(0,2));
        }

        // Sort the array.
        // Why this way? std::sort is always the first choice.
        std::sort (dates.begin(), dates.end());

        std::cout << "Sorted dates:\n";
        for (auto& date : dates)
        {
            std::cout << date.substr(6,2) + '/' +
                         date.substr(4,2) + '/' +
                         date.substr(0,4) + '\n';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas and suggestions for improving your code.

First of all it's best to combine all information about the dates in a stuckt (as also suggested by Mat) instead of having three-four separate arrays. For example:

```
struct Date{
   int year, month, day, date_int;

   Date(std::string date) : year(date_to_year(date)),  month(date_to_month(date)), 
             day(date_to_day(date)), date_int(date_to_int(day, month, year)) {}
}
```

The `date_int` integer is added for convenience when doing the sorting (see below) and I have also added a contructor to initialize the date from a string. The functions to extract year, month and day are quite simple if you use built-in string manipulations like for example [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) (to extract a substring) and [`std::atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) (to convert a string to an int):

```
inline int date_to_year(std::string date){
  return std::atoi(date.substr(6,4).c_str());
}

inline int date_to_month(std::string date){
  return std::atoi(date.substr(3,2).c_str());
}

inline int date_to_day(std::string date){
  return std::atoi(date.substr(0,2).c_str());
}
```

I would also use some standard container, like [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), to store the dates. Example use:

```
// Make the container
std::vector<Date> dates;

// Make a new date and add it to the container
std::sting date = "11/05/2001"
Date newdate(date);
dates.push_back(newdate);
```

One advantage of this is that vector takes care of memory allocation and deallocation for you so you don't have to think about this aspect. Also if you want to remove one date from the list you don't have to go through all three arrays you can simply use `dates.erase (dates.begin()+i-1)` to delete the i'th date in the container.

When reading in dates I would also check if the date is a viable date and if not then ask the user to enter a new date. Some useful checks to perform: is the year/day/month a positive integer?, is `day<32`?, is `month < 13`? and so on. If you want to be really thorough then you should also add checks about Feb. 29.

To sort the dates I would use a library instead of writing this yourself (unless that is the point of the exercise). For example [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) can be used for this. Instead of comparing year, month and day at the same time you can map the date uniquely to an integer using for example:

```
inline int date_to_int(int day, int month, int year){
  return year*10000 + month*100 + day;
}
```

If you have `date_int` in your `Date` struct then you can sort the dates very simply:

```
// Comparison function for two dates based on date_int
inline bool compare_dates(const Date &a, const Date &b){
  return a.date_int > b.date_int;
}

// Sort dates using compare_dates as the comparison function
std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end(), compare_dates);
```

If you have to implement the sorting function yourself then you can still use a comparison based on `date_int` to avoid having to compare year, month and day seperately.